Calculating Lateral Load Take Down
So this is the part of the project I am trying to do:
"Two load take downs in the vertical and lateral directions, from the roof level to the
foundation considering both normal loads and progressive collapse (i.e. alternative load
paths) if, say, on one side of the building the ground columns are removed (e.g. damaged
by a truck impact)".
The part I am in charge of is doing a lateral load takedown. I have to use Eurocode. I am finding the wind loads for the windward face of the building. I determined the windward face to be the left side of the building, then I determined the wind pressure using the equation Wp = q * (Cpe - Cpi), where q is given and coefficient of external and internal pressure is given by tables in Eurocode.  this is just an image of the ground floor. The windward side is the left, the core of our building is in the middle with the staircases. I have found the wind force by finding the wind pressure and multiplying it by the area of the wall to find the wind force. How do I then distribute it towards the slabs then columns then to foundations as well as the core. I am unsure of how to carry out a lateral load path.
